# HTML parsing in Java

Tags: java, html, html-parsing

Basically if I have a string that looks like this:

`%22Hello+World+%26+Hello+World%22`

because I took it from HTML, how do I get Java to make this say Hello World & Hello World, aka replace the HTML pieces with text?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

URLDecoder:

```
java.net.URLDecoder.decode("%22Hello+World+%26+Hello+World%22", "UTF-8")
```

**Update**: Modified to pass in the encoding as the second parameter.

Comment: thanks! that did it...except it's deprecated...is there a better way?

Comment: @JPC, I updated my answer to pass in the encoding.  This version of the method is not deprecated.

Comment: @JPC  If you had read the JavaDocs for the method in the document linked by Dancrumb, you might have noticed the deprecated method has the text "Deprecated. The resulting string may vary depending on the platform's default encoding. Instead, use the decode(String,String) method to specify the encoding."  Or to put that a different and more blunt way, in future, try RTFM.